# PHP - Hide one value when printing an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, drupal

I'm trying to print out the role of an user for a Fourm made with drupal 7. I use this code to print out there roles: `print implode(', ', $account->roles);`. This works, but it always displays 2 roles, `authencated user` and an other role. I wan't to hide `authencated user` when printing the array.

- Bramhaag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unset that property in your object or to put the role which you want in a variable.

```
print implode(', ', unset($account->roles->property));
```

**UPDATE:**

```
print end($account->roles);
```

this will print the last element in array. further you`ll be able to check if it is an administrator or no depending on this.

```
$last_role = end($account->roles);
if ($last_role == 'administrator') {} else {}
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET in /home/u752353545/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/styles/naked/advanced-forum.naked.author-pane.tpl.php on line 30` line 30: `print implode(', ', unset($account->roles->authencated user));`

Comment: `print_r($account->roles);`  - can you show me what this line is printing?

Comment: `Array ( [2] => authenticated user [3] => administrator )`